# combination of floating and fixed width li

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My HTML

```
                    </div><!-- /end .topbar -->

                    <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="first"><a href="#">Time added</a></li>
                            <li class="first"><a href="#">Price</a></li>
                            <li class="last"><a href="#">Discount</a></li>
                            <li class="delete"><a href="#"></a></li>
                    </ul><!-- /end .nav -->
                    <div class="done hidden">

                        <a href="#" class="button">done</a>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /end .mast -->
        </div><!-- /end .inner -->
</div><!-- /end #page -->
```

My CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

ul.nav{
    height:45px;
    background:#36d6be;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;

}

ul.nav li.first{
    width:33.333333%;
    float:left;
    border-right:solid 2px #3cefd4;
    height:45px;
}

ul.nav li.last{
    width:26.04166666666667%;
    float:left;
    border-right:solid 2px #3cefd4;
    height:45px;
}

ul.nav li.delete{
    float:left;
    width:56px;
    height:45px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q3LGW/

I have 4 li out of which first two are equal in size 33% and third is (33% - 56px) for last delete trash icon. But I am not able to create a fixed width last li which is float left.

Comment: *Not able to create a fixed width last li* - Correct.  And what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first three list items have a 2px right border, adding up to 6px. This means you need to deduct a further 6 px frm your last list item:

http://jsfiddle.net/q3LGW/2/

```
ul.nav li.delete {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

---

ALTERNATIVELY:

You can change the box-sizing property so that borders are included in the width of the box. I recommend that as the better solution. All you need to do is add this at the top of your CSS file:

```
*,
*:after,
*:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you use this method, you can also increase the width of that last list item to 58px.

http://jsfiddle.net/q3LGW/4/

Comment: I've approved an edit by Leandro Ruel that adds box-sizing:border-box to your pseudo elements :before and :after, but this isn't required for the current CSS you're using on your site, and so is best not included. Use no more CSS than you need to get things done on your website.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use display: table in the 
`<ul>`
and display:table-cell to the 
`<li>`
CHeck this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3LGW/5/)

```
ul.nav{
    height:45px;
    background:#36d6be;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    display:table;

}

ul.nav li.first{
    width:33.333333%;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:solid 2px #3cefd4;
    height:45px;
}

ul.nav li.last{
    width:26.04166666666667%;
    display:table-cell;
    border-right:solid 2px #3cefd4;
    height:45px;
}

ul.nav li.delete{
    display:table-cell;
    width:56px;
    height:45px;
}
```